# Calls error on ffmpeg module which doesnt have error attribute

Tags: python, openai-api, openai-whisper

Basically im using OpenAI whisper. Im using the code they give as a sample in the github repo. When i run it on command line or normally, it says the module ffmpeg doesnt have an attribute called error which whisper is calling for some reason.

Code(Just the sample code they supply on the github):

```
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("base")

# load audio and pad/trim it to fit 30 seconds
audio = whisper.load_audio("audio.mp3")
audio = whisper.pad_or_trim(audio)

# make log-Mel spectrogram and move to the same device as the model
mel = whisper.log_mel_spectrogram(audio).to(model.device)

# detect the spoken language
_, probs = model.detect_language(mel)
print(f"Detected language: {max(probs, key=probs.get)}")

# decode the audio
options = whisper.DecodingOptions()
result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)

# print the recognized text
print(result.text)
```

Im running on VScode, and i tried on the terminal with `whisper audio.mp3` as well, all of them give the same error:

> AttributeError: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'Error

Edit: Why is the error coming? i have the code right, and have the module installed to

Comment: @СергейКох i think i clarified it now?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install whisper using the command pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git

You can watch the answer in
https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/251